# При попытке запустить форму создается исключение

Tags: c#, winforms

Сообщение исключения
**Выполнение данной операции во время изменения размеров автозаполняемого столбца невозможно.**
Что это за столбец и как дождаться "изменения размеров столбца" и запустить форму?

```
private void խումբ5ToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Group_5 newGroup5 = new Group_5();
    newGroup5.ShowDialog(this);//вот здесь дает исключение
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При авторесайзе грида заполнять его до инициализации - не получается, насколько я понял.

Как вариант решения, можно сделать то, что советуют [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26628115/3768545):

> Добавляем после `InitializeComponent();` формы отключение авторесайза:
>
> ```
> this.dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.DisableResizing;
> ```
>
> А в методе на событии загрузки `GridWrapper_Load` включаем обратно:
>
> ```
> this.dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.AutoSize;
> ```

Comment: но у меня есть и другие формы которые я инициализирую тем же способом что и этот но в них не дает исключение?

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/48531)

Comment: Главная причина - в авторесайзе. Чем отличается именно эта форма - без понятия, код ваш, вам виднее.

Самый простой вариант - отключить авторесайз, заполнить форму данными, включить авторесайз.

Comment: Не хотите ли все-таки написать полный ответ?

Comment: @NickVolynkin скопировал основную мысль.